# if else define for preprocessor

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

```
//initial code:

#define MYDEBUG YES

#if (defined(MYDEBUG) && MYDEBUG == YES)
#define NATIVEUNITID @"unitid_debug"
#else
#define NATIVEUNITID @"unitid_release"
#endif


//somewhere inside the code
```

`NATIVEUNITID`  is `@"unitid_release"`

May be I do not understand something. But why? What is the proper way to define 
`NATIVEUNITID` using the other define?

I've tried both `#if (MYDEBUG)` and `#if (MYDEBUG == true)` but I obtain the same result.

Please, help me to understand this simple case. How can I receive 
`NATIVEUNITID`  is `@"unitid_debug"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor cannot evaluate `==` for "strings".

You could retain your notation if you write `#DEFINE YES 1`

Answer (score 0):

To improve [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40803378/1979882)

```
#if !defined(YES)
#define YES (BOOL)1
#endif
#if !defined(NO)
#define NO  (BOOL)0
#endif
```

before

```
#define MYDEBUG YES
```